# Java no encuentra los archivos .class

Tags: java

estoy empezando con Java y tengo un problema que no soy capaz de resolver y me tiene un poco loco.

Instale JDK en un equipo con windows, y todo funciono ok, configuré las variables path y classpath en el equipo, ejecuté un pequeño archivo de prueba, se compilo bien, y mostró lo que se esperaba por consola. Hasta aqui todo bien.

Depúes instalé NetBeans en el equipo, se instaló bien, y los archivos en el se ejecutan de forma correcta.

El problema viene que al intentar volver a usar la consola, no me encuentra ninguno de los archivos .class que se generaron al compilar los archivos .java, he revisado que ejecuto el comando desde la ruta propia en la que se encuentran los archivos .java y .class, ambos con el mismo nombre, el código es super simple.

```
C:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1>dir
 El volumen de la unidad C es Windows
 El número de serie del volumen es: DED8-2DDB

 Directorio de C:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1
15/09/2022  15:14    <DIR>          .
15/09/2022  15:14    <DIR>          ..
14/09/2022  21:36    <DIR>          mavenproject1
14/09/2022  17:11               445 MiModulo.class
14/09/2022  17:07               315 MiModulo.java
15/09/2022  15:17    <DIR>          PROG01_programa1
15/09/2022  19:42               657 PROG01_programa1.class

15/09/2022  19:41               572 PROG01_programa1.java
               4 archivos          1.989 bytes
               4 dirs  21.467.275.264 bytes libres

C:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1>java PROG01_programa1
```

Si ejecuto devuelve:

```
C:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1>java PROG01_programa1
Error: Could not find or load main class PROG01_programa1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PROG01_programa1
```

si lo hago indicando ese mismo directorio con -cp funciona:

```
C:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1>java -cp \Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1 PROG01_programa1
Módulo Profesional - PROGRAMACIÓN. UNIDAD DE TRABAJO 01
Introducción a la programación
Fernán Fernández Diez
Lugo, Lugo
15/09/2022
Programa1
```

C:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1>

Os lo paso:

```
/**
* La clase PROG01_programa1 implementa una aplicación que
* simplemente imprime "Módulo Profesional - PROGRAMACIÓN. UNIDAD DE TRABAJO 01" en pantalla.
*/
public class PROG01_programa1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Módulo Profesional - PROGRAMACIÓN. UNIDAD DE TRABAJO 01"); // Muestra la cadena de caracteres.
System.out.println("Introducción a la programación");
System.out.println("Fernán Fernández Diez");
System.out.println("Lugo, Lugo");
System.out.println("15/09/2022");
System.out.println("Programa1");
    }
}
```

Tenia entendido que si ejecutas desde donde están los archivos no debería haber problemas. La Classpath la tengo apuntando a la carpeta lib de la instalación

```
C:\Users\ferna\OneDrive\Escritorio\Nano\DAW\JAVA\UD1>set CLASSPATH
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\lib
```

Traté de agregar la ruta donde tengo los archivos .class que se generan para este ejemplo, pero el error es el mismo.

Desconozco si al instalar NetBeans exista algún problema con el CLASSPATH (ya que en netbeans funciona bien).

Answer (score 0):

indicar que finalmente encontré el error, y es que al configurar la CLASSPATH no había incluido al principio de la misma los ".;", por lo que no estaba buscando los archivos dentro del propio directorio.

Los agregé y ya funciona de forma correcta.

Saludos